# How can I hide the ReSharper code analysis menu without disabling completely

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I'm evaluating ReSharper and so far it's pretty good. However I can't stand the little action list popup that appears next to your cursor: [image]

That said, I find some of the options useful. Ideally I would only see the menu when I click `Alt`+`Enter`.

I know that I can disable this feature entirely by unchecking "Enable code analysis", but as I said, I'd prefer to keep the feature.

Comment: Good question! This is exactly my opinion also! If the list can't be hidden, is it possible to move the action list without disabling the entire feature? Anyone?

Comment: I think if you use it for a while, you will start to find it to be useful. I was also initially annoyed by it, but found that it is valuable as an indicator of when you can use Alt-Enter. Otherwise, you would have no idea when that option is available to you. I'd definitely love for it to be a little less intriusive though!

Comment: You´re right @rob-h. The icon is important, but do you now how to change its' position? Just a few pixels, let's say to the left? At least so it doesn't hide any code part?

Comment: Sorry, I've never seen any options for that. Typically the code I'm working on is indented enough that there's not much overlap (e.g. just namespace declarations in C#)

Answer (score 1):

In VS2013 with R# 9.1, the popup sits in the gutter where it won't obscure your code:

[image]